# Monitoring uptime and health of several services (web service, oracle, web app)

Tags: monitoring, sendmail, health-monitoring, uptime

I have several services growing in activity. I'm looking for a simple service that can monitor them (web service, oracle, web app), and send an email when one is down.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: There are several apps for this purpose, for example Pingdom. I have also developed an uptime & performance monitoring app called Pinglist so might as well check it out: https://pingli.st/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go have a look at the xymon system. It is simple and easy youse and scales well. I used xymon at several organizations and it is awesome. The user community is also very vibrant and helpfull.

Other systems you can look at are Nagios and OpenNMS. These are more complex though and might be overkill.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! We went the Nagios way.